# Generic Types and LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq, generics

I write two public classes (test1, test2) with two fields, e. g. 'Name' and 'Surname'.
Then, I would like to fill data from a database to this objects.
My first try was:

```
public List<T> FillFromDB<T>()
{
   IQueryable<T> query =
      from tbl in _table
      select new T {Name=tbl.name, Surname=tbl.surname}
}
```

But T don't know the fields. What could I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make `test1` and `test2` imlpement an interface with those properties and put a where clause on the type `T`.

Comment: Do they have a base type that you can use instead of T?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a common interface (or class) from which `Test1` and `Test2` would inherit from and then specify the necessary constraints on the type parameter of `FillFromDb`.

```
public interface IHasName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
public class Test1 : IHasName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
public class Test2 : IHasName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
public List<T> FillFromDB<T>()
    where T : new(), IHasName
{
   IQueryable<T> query =
      from tbl in _table
      select new T {Name=tbl.name, Surname=tbl.surname}
}
```

Comment: I think you'll also have to add `new()` to the constraints.  And technically you don't need `class`.

Comment: Could be IHasName abstract?

Comment: @ANKH Yes, you could use an abstract base class instead of an interface.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I get a build error. I call FillFromDB<Test1>(). Although I get the error in verbose_mode, I don't know the problem.

Comment: @ANKH Hard to say what the issue might be without seeing the code.  Perhaps you should add an 'Update' section to your original question demonstrating the updated code.

Comment: Mm. If I use Visual Studio Community 2013 the program runs correct. If I use Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate an error appears.